# If object contains any substring in an array

Tags: javascript, object

I've got an array of keywords like this:

```
var keywords = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
```

And an object like this:

```
var person = {
    name: 'John',
    quote: 'I love the color blue'
};
```

How would I determine if any value in the person object contains any of the keywords?

***Update***

This is what I ended up using. Thanks to everyone!

http://jsbin.com/weyal/10/edit?js,console

Comment: Show what you have tried and clarify whether or not you want to handle cases with nested objects string arrays/maps in your searched object.

Comment: Loop the `person` object, split the string by words, then loop the `keywords` array and compare, or use `indexOf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function isSubstring(w){
  for(var k in person) if(person[k].indexOf(w)!=-1) return true;
  return false
}

keywords.some(isSubstring) // true if a value contains a keyword, else false
```

This is case-sensitive and does not respect word boundaries.

---

#### 2nd Answer

Here's a way that is case-**insensitive**, and **does** respect word boundaries.

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b('+keywords.join('|')+')\\b','i');
function anyValueMatches( o, r ) {
  for( var k in o ) if( r.test(o[k]) ) return true;
  return false;
}

anyValueMatches(person,regex) // true if a value contains a keyword, else false
```

If any `keywords` contain characters that have special meaning in a RegExp, they would have to be escaped.

Comment: Nice answer! I wasn't familiar with `some`.

Answer (score 3):

If `person` only contains strings, this should do it:

```
for (var attr in person) {
  if (person.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
    keywords.forEach(function(keyword) {
      if (person[attr].indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
        console.log("Found " + keyword + " in " + attr);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you want deep search, then you need a function that recurses on objects.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each property in the object, then split the property into tokens and check if each token is in the array using `indexOf`.  `indexOf` will not be available on older browsers, I believe IE < 9, but you can find a shim in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var person = {
    name: 'John',
    quote: 'I love the color blue'
};

var person2 = {
    name: 'John',
    quote: 'I love the color orange'
};

var keywords = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

function contains(obj, keywords){
    for(x in person){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
            var tokens = obj[x].split(/\s/);
            for(var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
                if(keywords.indexOf(tokens[i])!= -1){
                   return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

alert(contains(person, keywords));
alert(contains(person2, keywords));
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/BaC5p/

Comment: Accidental `window.x` ;)

Comment: @Amadan not sure what your referring to?

Comment: `for(x in person)` without `var`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function testKeyWords(keywords) {
    var keyWordsExp = new RegExp('\b(' + keywords.join(')|(') + ')\b', 'g');
    for(var key in person) {
        if(keyWordsExp.test(person[key])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most comfortable way is to add `.contains(str)` to the `String` and to the `Array` prototype:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.contains === 'undefined') {
    String.prototype.contains = function (it) {
        return this.indexOf(it) != -1;
    };
}
if (typeof Array.prototype.contains === 'undefined') {
    Array.prototype.contains = function (it) {
        for (var i in this) {
            var elem = this[i].toString();
            if (elem.contains(it)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

If you put the code above into a `.js` file which you include, you can use it everywhere in your code like so:

```
var b = ["A Bell", "A Book", "A Candle"];

var result1 = b.contains("Book"); // returns: true, it is contained in "A Book"
var result2 = b.contains("Books"); // returns: false, it is not contained
```